# Remove duplicates with exception

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, excel-2016

I have PDF I'm converting to a excel table and removing duplicates that the process makes, I was able to tune it down enough to extract some useful information, but now I hit a roadblock.

```
let
Fonte = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents("S:\Aplicativo\API Relatório\RelSC18102023_085032456.pdf"), [Implementation="1.3"]),
#"Data Expandido" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Fonte, "Data", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3","Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13"},{"Data.Column1", "Data.Column2", "Data.Column3", "Data.Column4", "Data.Column5", "Data.Column6", "Data.Column7", "Data.Column8","Data.Column9", "Data.Column10", "Data.Column11", "Data.Column12", "Data.Column13"}),
#"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Data Expandido",{"Id", "Name", "Kind"}),
#"Remover Nulls" = Table.FromColumns(List.Zip(List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(Table.ToRows(#"Colunas Removidas"), each if List.NonNullCount(_)=0 then null else List.RemoveNulls(_))))),
#"Duplicatas Removidas" = Table.Distinct(#"Remover Nulls"),
#"Duplicatas Removidas1" = Table.Distinct(#"Duplicatas Removidas", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7"})
in
#"Duplicatas Removidas1"
```

When I do the last Table.Distinct, it removes all duplicates from the table... including a line that show the client id when it repeats (the table goes something like, order id, client id, then other order info). What I wanted was to put a conditional before the Table.Distinct to the tune of "if column1 = "Client:" do nothing, else Table.Distinct (etc) in blablabla".

Would that be possible? If so, what is the correct sintax to achieve it? It would also help me with another problem with the table (where sometimes a order info is equal to another order and is removed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter Column<>"Client:", do Table.Distinct, add back Column1="Client:"

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepNameHere", each [Column1] <> "Client:"))& Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStepNameHere", each [Column1] = "Client:")
```

To preserve row sorting, add column ... index column ... filter/unduplicate, then resort afterwards

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.Distinct(Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Column1] <> "Client:"),List.Difference(Table.ColumnNames(#"Added Index"),{"Index"}))& Table.SelectRows(#"Added Index", each [Column1] = "Client:"),
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Index", Order.Ascending}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"Index"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Didn't work any way I tried so far. It either removes all client id lines without the index, or still removes lines with repeated client id with the index. Where would you put the filter in the code? I updated the question with how I tried.

Comment: Right done that, and it just doesn't remove any duplicates at all. What I figured up is that the index makes it so that no line is removed in the table.distinct because every line has a diferent index value so they're all nominal unique entrances instead of duplicates. If I don't put the index, then all lines with "Client:" get removed AND no duplicates get removed either.

Comment: With that and adding some of the other columns I wanted sorted out, it finally worked! Thanks!